# double integrals equivalent definition

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Is there is any equivalent definitions for double integral, for example in single variable integrals there is these equivalent integrability statements :

> $f$ is Riemann integrable $\iff$ for each $\epsilon \gt 0$ , there is
>   a partition $P$ that upholds : $U(P,f) - L(P,f) \lt \epsilon \iff$ for each $\epsilon \gt 0$, there is $\delta \gt 0$, that for each Partition with its norm $\lt \delta$, it upholds that:  $U(P,f) - L(P,f) \lt \epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

You can try a similar definition of a [multiple Riemann integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral#Mathematical_definition).

Caution: it is not necessarily the same as an iterated Riemann integral.  Thus for

$$ J = \int_a^b \int_c^d f(x,y)\; dx \; dy$$
it is possible that for each $y \in [a,b]$, the function $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ is Riemann integrable on $[c,d]$, and the resulting Riemann
integral $\int_c^d f(x,y)\; dx$ is a Riemann integrable function on $[a,b]$, but the double Riemann integral does **not** exist.

For example, let $a = c = 0$, $b = d = 2 \pi$, and 
$$f(x,y) = \sin(n(y) x)$$ 
where $n(y) = 1$ if $y$ is rational and $0$ if $y$ is irrational.
Thus $\int_0^{2\pi} f(x,y)\; dy = 0$ for all $x$.  But this does
not behave well with respect to partitions.